# Sorting of solr documents based on search term in solr

Tags: solr

I would like to sort solr documents based on searched term. For example the search term is "stringABC"

Then the order of the results should be

stringABC,
stringABCxxxx,
xxxxstringABCxxxx

The solr document will contain lot of fileds ex: title, description, path, article No, Product code etc..

And the default field will contain more than one field ex: title, description and path.

So the solr doc will only be returned when the search term satisfied any field from the default field.

Answer (score 0):

Use three fields - one with the exact string, one with a EdgeNgramTokenizer and one with an NgramTokenizer. You can then use `qf=field1^10 field2^5 field3` to score hits in these fields according to how you want to prioritize them between each other.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @MatsLindh. To use qf should I use dismax query parser? Currently I am using Standard query parser.

Comment: Correct. You can still do the same, you'll have to search all three fields explicitly (`field1:stringABC^10 field2:stringABC^5 field3:stringABC`). I recommend using the edismax parser, though.

Comment: My query is 
q.op=AND&q={!join+from%3DbaseProduct+to%3DbaseProduct}general_search_NGRAM:XXXX&qt=/select&fq={!tag%3DtagFeatures}(*:*)&fq=cq_commerceType:"article"&sort=rankingValue+desc&rows=12&start=0&facet.field=XXXXXX&facet.field={!ex%3DtagFeatures+key%3DfeaturesTagged}features&facet.field=XXXXX&facet.field=XXXXXXXXX&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=-1&group=true&group.field=baseProduct&group.ngroups=true&group.limit=1.
once I receive all articles I am grouping them and I want to sort the groups based on the search result. I tried above option edismax but its not working.

Comment: can you please check my above comment? @MatsLindh

Comment: You should be able to expand your `q` parameter as given above. When it comes to group sorting, that'll be a different use case - try first and see if you get the result you want.